# how to use the integer values in vaadin progressbar?

Tags: java, groovy, progress-bar, progress

I have three integer values  Total, right and left. How can i use it in a progressbar. for example, Sum = Total-(right+left). This sum is the remaining progress. Where Total is Full value.
I am using a vaadin progressbar. vaadin version-7.6.3
How can i convert. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProgressBar.setValue(..) takes a Float between 0 and 1 as a parameter. (See: https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/ProgressBar.html#setValue-float- )

This means that you need to scale your value to this range, say value = index / total If the index is Integer between 0 and total.

Comment: Thank you tatu, if am right something like float value = (right+left)/Total, Progressbar.setvalue(value)